# Can something like map!(&:strip) be written?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to remove white space of array elements, but at the same time I want this to be inline replacement. Is something like this can be done..

```
lines[3..lines.length-4].map!(&:strip).delete_if { |table_name| table_name == "" }
```

Comment: If you tried it and it worked then it definitely can be done =)

Comment: It returns what i expected, but its not getting replaced..

Comment: why in-place updates? are inputs so big to be worried about creating a new array?

Comment: It's nice that you added description of the problem, but you completely changed your code sample. And what's more important is that this one works, while the first version didn't.

Comment: if files are big and processing is done line-by-line I'd recommend another approach (generators). BTW, KL-7 is right, you shouldn't change the question that way, now the existing answers make no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because `lines[3..lines.length-4]` returns a new array, not a partial "reference" to the old one (so your `map!` is then just modifying in-place this new array).

An idea:

```
(3..lines.length-4).each { |idx| lines[idx].strip! }
```

Comment: I believe you meant `strip!`. And OP needs filtering as well.

Comment: @KL-7, indeex, strip! There was no delete_if when I saw the question :-( +1 yours, that does it. However, I don't think that's the correct way of handling this kind of processing. In-place updates are ugly.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `map!` on `lines[3..lines.length-4]` this method is called not on your original array but on a new one, that contains slice of the original `lines` array. If what you need is to replace part of your `lines` array with its stripped and filtered elements you can do it like that:

```
lines[3..lines.length-4] = lines[3..lines.length-4].map(&:strip).reject { |tn| tn == "" }
```

Here you explicitly override slice of `lines` array after striping and filtering elements it contains.